# Try to install the Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows 7 OS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

In Windows 7 OS, in disk management utility, it shows "unallocated" disk partition size as 50GB and other 5 partitions in my system. In Ubuntu 16.04 installer, it is not showing the partitions properly when try to install the Ubuntu. This unallocated partition is merged with another partition and the size as 100GB. Not sure that how to install the Ubuntu 16.04 OS and why it is not detecting the partitions properly.

2 years back, I have installed Ubuntu some version in this system. This may be removed when install the Windows 7 OS. This is the system history. In Windows 7 boot manager, Ubuntu option is there, but it is not booting.

The additional details:
In disk management utility, it shows as "Dynamic storage", not "Basic". In dynamic storage, the partitions are "simple". Whether I need to convert this dynamic to basic for Ubuntu 16.04 OS. Please confirm this.

Comment: Ubuntu used to not even see dynamic partitions. It is a proprietary Windows partitioning system to get around the 4 primary partition limit. Somewhat like LVM in Linux. New systems use gpt but for then Windows has to be UEFI boot. More Info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Comment: What he said ^^^